# Alt Codes and jQuery keyup event - Value not updated when alt key is released

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div style="color: blue"></div>
<input type="text">

<script>
$('input').keyup(function(){
     $('div').html($(this).val());
 });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NMqhW/

Basically when alt codes are used the release of the alt key seems to fire the event; however, the value of the triggering element at the time the alt key is released seems to not be updated with the alt code symbol. (At-least in my chrome version 34; Windows)

Alt does appear to be firing as if I add a console.log to the keyup it does trigger when alt is released.

Is there any way to make it work (*ideally without a hack*) such that the Alt code change also updates the DIV?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988403/alt-keyup-event-dont-work-on-firefox

Comment: In that particular case the OP needed to know if the alt key was being released. That works ok here, but the value of the triggering field when that happens is not updated with the alt-key-symbol as far as I can tell.

Comment: don't know about windows.. but it is working in Ubuntu.. :/ and on Ubuntu we have to press like "Ctrl+Shift+U" release "U" and enter the hex code of the Alt code equivalent...

Answer (score -2):

```js
$('input').keyup(function(){
     $('div').html($(this).val());
 });
```

```html
<input type="text">
<div style="color: blue"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```